# Javascript does not execute branch IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Why does this condition always execute the ELSE and not the IF branch. Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (document.getElementById("analyses").value == 'distance'){

loadScript('/static/distance.js', function()
{
     console.log('done loading');
    });
}else{
loadScript('/static/geoClusters.js', function()
{   
console.log('done loading');
});
 }
});
```

The form has several select tags with different option values as such:

```
<select name="analysis" id="analyses">
     <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Analysis</option>
      <option value="distance">distance</option>
      <option value="clustered">clustering</option>
</select>
```

I can't see what's wrong with the if-else statment.

Thanks

EDIT

Thanks for all the great suggestions, I think the way the code is structured the way suggested by @trebuchet works:

```
$("#analyses").bind("change",function(){
.............code.......
});
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: You've got a good answer on how to do this with jQuery but if you're trying to do it without you can look at this question: [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your code is structured it will only run once on page load - in which case the value of the select will always be an empty string. If you want it to respond to changes:

```
$("#analyses").bind("change",function(){

    if (document.getElementById("analyses").value == 'distance'){

        loadScript('/static/distance.js', function()
        {
           console.log('done loading');
        });
    }else{
        loadScript('/static/geoClusters.js', function()
        {   
            console.log('done loading');
        });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You actually can't use `value` like that on an HTML select element -- it has the property `selectedIndex`, but not `selectedValue`.  JQuery does implement `val()` on select elements, though:

```
if ($("#analyses").val() == 'distance')
```

If you're doing it with straight Javascript, then you have to first get the selected index, then the value from the `option` element:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("analyses");
if (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value)
```

---

To answer your question, with the original code, Javascript will always execute the `else` branch, because `document.getElementById("analyses").value` is `undefined`, which Javascript typecasts as "false" in a boolean statement.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9EAsm/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried your example in fiddle and modified it a bit, but I get the same problem. http://jsfiddle.net/9EAsm/7/

Comment: @user94628 there are script errors in your Fiddle ... see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kMHVS/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help...the way my code was set up it wasn't working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

at the time of document.ready fires, the value of analyses is always going to be "" because that is the default selected option.  I'm not sure since the first option is disabled why this happens but apparently that's what is happening.

If you change the default selected option value to "distance" then it does fire you can see here:

```
<select name="analysis" id="analyses">
     <option value="" disabled="disabled">Select Analysis</option>
      <option value="distance" selected="selected">distance</option>
      <option value="clustered">clustering</option>
</select>​
```

I posted a test here too: http://jsfiddle.net/BKD4u/